# CSS. Show div from bottom

Tags: css, show, hidden

I have bottom line, on the right side there are grey div, I want on hover to show up full that div. At the beginning grey div is hidden. How could I solve this problem? Thanks!

[There is fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/benasg/75eycjkd/)

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="footer_right_wrapper"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
/* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
/* Negative indent footer by its height */
margin: 0 auto -61px;
/* Pad bottom by footer height */
padding: 0 0 60px;
}

#footer {
height: 61px;
background-color: red;
color: black;
}

.container {
height: 61px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#footer_right_wrapper {
width: 100px;
height: 217px;
background-color: grey;
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:hover` selector attribute:

**show/hide grey element:**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/or2y2fzg/

```
#footer_right_wrapper {
    display: none;
}
#footer:hover #footer_right_wrapper {
    display: block;
}
```

If I understood you correctly, you want to show the grey div once you hover your cursor over the #footer?

.

**Expand grey element:**

If you want to expand grey element to fill #footer element: http://jsfiddle.net/r30nxzxk/

```
#footer_right_wrapper {
    width: 100px;

    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
#footer_right_wrapper:hover {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note that I added CSS transition to have a smooth UX.

Comment: I want that grey div expands to top. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/benasg/75eycjkd/1/